# Array length if statement?

Tags: javascript

I made a simple Image slider in JS for practice, but for some reason the variable Amount is equal to 3, which it should be, I tested by printing 3, but for my if statements I have to divide by 2 for the first (which makes it work ((function next() )), but for the second it does not work if I divide by 2 or do Amount alone (the back() function)

I do not know why it is doing this, please can someone explain?
Thanks!

```
var Images = ["http://www.industus.com/test/wat1.png", "http://www.industus.com/test/wat2.png", "http://www.industus.com/test/wat3.png"];
var CurrentImage = -1;
var Amount = Images.length;
function next() {
  if (CurrentImage <= Amount /2) {
    CurrentImage = CurrentImage + 1;
    document.getElementById("Picture").src = Images[CurrentImage];
  }
}
function back() {
  if (CurrentImage >= Amount /2) {
    CurrentImage = CurrentImage - 1;
    document.getElementById("Picture").src = Images[CurrentImage];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For going forward, you want to test whether the index is smaller than the *largest* valid index, with is `Amount - 1`

```
CurrentImage < (Amount-1)
```

For going backwards, you want to test whether the index is larger that the *smallest* valid index, which is `0`:

```
 CurrentImage > 0
```